# How to reference a properties value inside the schema attribute of an entity?

Tags: spring

There is an entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITMMASTER" , schema = "TOMCTB")
public class Article {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ITMREF_0")
    private String code_article;

    @Column(name = "ACCCOD_0")
    private String acccod;

    public String getCode_article() {
        return code_article;
    }

    public void setCode_article(String code) {
        this.code_article = code;
    }

    public String getAcccod() {
        return acccod;
    }

    public void setAcccod(String acccod) {
        this.acccod = acccod;
    }

}
```

I want to make the `schema` attribute to be dynamic depending on a `properties` file property value , for example : `env.schema = TOMEXPL`.

How to achieve that ?

Comment: If you selected the `spring` tag I suppose that you are talk about spring properties management. You can inject properties only in beans managed by the DI container.

Comment: So you mean that it is impossible to reference a property inside the entity attribute ?

Comment: Yes you can't as the value of this attribute is a String constant and a String constant in Java is : `static final String` and not `static String`. The difference is important because if it was `static String` it could be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tried it but I guess this should work.

```
public class DynamicNamingStrategy extends DefaultNamingStrategy {

   @Value("db.table.name") 
   private String name;

   @Override
   public  String tableName(String tableName) {
      return name;
   }
   ...
}




 SessionFactory sessionFactory;
  Configuration config = new AnnotationConfiguration()
                         .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                         .setNamingStrategy( new DynamicNamingStrategy() );
  sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
  session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```